# How to send email with high priority using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, email

I am using the below code to send email from my web application in ASP.net:

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(to);
        mail.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text, "something", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.Subject = "Request";
        mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.Body = "This is a sample email";
        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        //Add the Creddentials- use your own email id and password
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, pass);
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(mail);
```

Even though the priority of the email has been set to *high*, but the sent email will go the spam box after the first time of sending an email.

How can I send an email that appears in my Inbox and not in my spam area regardless of the number of times that I send the email?

Comment: c# does not control the marking of email as spam..it is your email provider or maybe the content of email that causes it to be marked as spam

Comment: The sender cannot control which box the email goes into. Otherwise spammers would just put it in the inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, (well, I guess more fortunately for our sake) this is completely out of your control (in terms of the straight up coding). A lot of spam filters use [Bayesian analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering) to determine what is spam and what isn't (other techniques are used as well, but this is just a references as to how they can work). So, changing the content of the message could help you, but there is no way to code it to avoid spam.

Many websites suggest adding their sending address to your address book. This is a way that will possibly work because they are often marked as safe, but I do not believe that that is guaranteed to work for all systems.

Comment: It's sounds like you're saying all spam filters use the same technique. Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: Nope, I was generalizing. All that I've heard of use that, but that is by no means fact

Comment: @DanDrews I tried some ways to change the body of email and use tricky ways to show that the mail is not spam. but it seems to be useless. Do you have any suggestion about how to change the body in order turn the filtering system?

Comment: @Pedram have you ever signed up for a website that asks you to add the sending address to your address book of your email? This is because most systems handle those as safe senders. Just a thought, but I cannot say for sure if it will work